# How to build an inline form with multiple rows with Bootstrap v4?

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap v4, how can you build a form like the one seen below?

I'm trying to understand if I should be using form-inline with either multiple form-groups or multiple rows?

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/

[image: FORM]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use `form-group` and `fieldset`

`form-group` groups the input elements on the same line

`fieldset` makes the label appear above the input

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5wbeqmgc/2/

Not perfect, but a simple example using columns: https://jsfiddle.net/5wbeqmgc/4/

Comment: Thank you for the reply... Why is the margin between the fields gone?

Comment: Great. Thank you

Comment: I came to this page with the same question, however, it seems that this answer is _wrong_. If you follow the fiddle and make the window big enough, you'll see the controls inline instead of in a row inside both the `form-group` and the `fieldset`.